# IOR and denisity for Soda/Soft drink

Tags: materials, pbr

I'm working on creating a soda and i'm trying to create the material for the liquid (not using fluids)
My question is if there's a resource similar to https://physicallybased.info/ that provides information on Density and IOR for soft drinks/soda?

Comment: Soda is 95% water - IOR of water is 1.33 - just use that. Any additional refraction in soda would be caused by either the "bubbles" and/or ice - which depends on if you want to include them and if so, how (mesh/particles/shader/etc...).

Comment: Thank you Christopher! :)